# Calculating when the amount will be doubled using while loop

Tags: python

This is a simple exercise found in a book, which asks us to determine how long it takes for an amount to double at a given interest rate. My code is like this:

```
def main():
  x = eval(raw_input("Initial Principal: "))
  y = eval(raw_input("Interest rate: "))
  count = 0
  while x < 2*x:
      x = x * (1 + y)
      count = count + 1

  print (x)
  print (count)

main()
```

What it returns is:

`Initial Principal: 1000
 Interest rate: 0.5
 inf
 1734`

What's wrong with my code?
Also I wonder if the above code would work if my amount and interest is small, e.g. amount = 1 and interest rate = 0.05, since there would include some floating point arithmetic I guess.

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried to debug it...?

Comment: What do you think `x < 2*x` will do? It will loop *forever*.

Comment: ___Don't call `eval` on user input.___ Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/why-is-using-eval-a-bad-practice) or google "why is eval bad" and read any of the 5 thousand results. Just use `float` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The culprit is the fact that you write:

```
while x < 2*x:
```

Since `x > 0`, that relation will always be `False`, you do *not* compare the new `x` with the old `x`, you compare the new `x` with twice the new `x`.

We can solve this effectively by using a variable `x0` that store the initial amount:

```
def main():
  x = x0 = eval(raw_input("Initial Principal: "))
  y = eval(raw_input("Interest rate: "))
  count = 0
  while x < 2*x0:
      x = x * (1 + y)
      count = count + 1

  print (x)
  print (count)

main()
```

But there are still some problems with the code. For example you use `eval`. Do not use `eval` unless you absolutely have to: now a person can enter any type of Python code, also code that will break the system. Use `float(..)` instead to convert a `str`ing to an `int`:

```
def main():
  x = x0 = float(raw_input("Initial Principal: "))
  y = float(raw_input("Interest rate: "))
  count = 0
  while x < 2*x0:
      x = x * (1 + y)
      count = count + 1

  print (x)
  print (count)

main()
```

But now the code is still inefficient. There exists a fast way to calcuate the number of years using *logarithms*:

```
from math import log, ceil, pow

def main():
  x = x0 = float(raw_input("Initial Principal: "))
  y = float(raw_input("Interest rate: "))
  count = ceil(log(2.0, y+1.0))
  newx = x * pow(1.0+y, count)
  print (newx)
  print (count)
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is your while guard, which checks if the number is less than two times itself. To solve this, save the threshold you want to reach in a variable before the loop, and you have done:

```
threshold = 2 * x
count = 0
while x < threshold:
    x = x * (1 + y)
    count = count + 1
```

Comment: Oh right! I know what's wrong with the condition, the variable will keep on changing.

Comment: As pointed out by @Rawing, avoid to use eval of raw_input. It's safer to use `float(raw_input(...))` in your case, which converts the string into a float as required, and raises an exception if the string cannot be converted.